# How can I add a custom sidebar in the magento backend?

Tags: php, magento

I have created a custom module for the backend. Now I need to configure an admin template for my custom module.

I am able to create a new template for the frontend in magento. But I still don't understand, how to create a new theme for the admin side.

And also, I have designed my own header, footer and sidebars (left and right) for my new admin theme.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: signup for a free account at training.magento.com they have tons of free videos explaining how to work the backend

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento Admin custom theme not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600326/magento-admin-custom-theme-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

See the following link from Inchoo. They have an excellent module solution for creating a custom admin theme, without chopping up the default one. Its ridiculously simple as well. Its also upgrade proof.  I used it to add a few more attribute selections to the product list.

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/custom-admin-theme-in-magento/

You then just create your theme in /var/www/app/design/adminhtml/default/NAMEOFYOURTHEME

You can also just make css tweaks by adding /var/www/skin/adminhtml/default/NAMEOFYOURTHEME/custom.css (which is located in the default theme, so override it)

Comment: Thanks anyway, But I dont want to overrite the existing admin template but need to create new admin template for separate custom admin module created.